# Fitting multiple instances of the same scikit-learn model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to run multiple multinomial logistic regressions on my dataset. Once I run one, I am trying to append the model I just ran to a list, so I can access the specific model later.
Code looks something like this

```
models = []
for i in range(0, 10):
  model = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()
  model.fit(x,y)
  models.append(model)
```

Where x and y are different in each `for` iteration. The issue is that the coefficients/model that i get in each element of the final array "models", is the same as the final iteration of that for loop. I am assuming this is because I am just updating the reference each iteration and not creating a new Logistic Regression model each time. Can someone point me to a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in the [`clone` function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html).

> sklearn.base.clone(estimator, *, safe=True)[source]
>
> Constructs a new unfitted estimator with the same parameters.
> Clone does a deep copy of the model in an estimator without actually copying attached data. It yields a new estimator with the same parameters that has not been fitted on any data.

```py
from sklearn.base import clone

model = LogisticRegression()
new_model = clone(model)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you

Comment: Done, will keep that in mind from now on. Thank you for your help